# How can I add a custom property to the message I create in ActiveMQ web interface?

Tags: properties, message, activemq-classic, addition

How can I use the Activemq web interface to add a custom property to the message I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do this from the web console interface...would be a good feature though, [request it](http://activemq.apache.org/contributing.html)